# Basic explanation of Falcon and Dilithium

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, implementation, dilithium

I've been trying to search for toy examples of the round 3 digital signatures Rainbow, Falcon and Dilithium. Not a lot of actual implementation examples are out there. What I'm searching for are actual examples with numbers that explain how the two algorithms (Falcon and Dilithium) work (*key generation, signign and verification*), e.g. the parameter for Falcon could be `n = 4` or `n = 8`

Would anyone know where I could find some examples? I've already read through the official documentation several times as well as the source code of the submissions, but cannot follow the pure math without easy examples at all...

Comment: Forget about Rainbow, it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where to find examples for Dilithium and Falcon, but I found a toy-kyber code here: https://cryptopedia.dev/posts/kyber/. Hope it will help.